# How can I get the "type" of each attribute in a collection?

Tags: javascript

Is there a JS library that will tell me the types of each attribute in a collection?

I have an array of objects which is the result of a SQL db query.

The data looks like this:

```
[{
  id: "1",
  email: "donnyp@gmail.com",
  is_subscribed: null,
  name: "Don P",
  created_at: "2015-01-18 18:16:32"
},
{
  id: "2",
  email: "test@test.com",
  is_subsribed: "t",
  name: "Test Guy",
  created_at: "2015-01-30 12:05:55"
},
...]
```

I want an object that tells me the types of each "column". Something like this:

```
{
  id: "integer",
  email: "string",
  is_subscribed: "boolean",
  name: "string",
  created_at: "datetime"
}
```

**Edit**: This is not as simple as doing typechecks. The main issues I'm having here is that all values are strings except for nulls. That means I'd have to try to cast an entire column to a type, then check if that type is an integer. Repeat for each type I want to check.  So I'll have (# of types to test) X (# of objects) X (# of columns), which is a lot to calculate, so if there's some smarter way I'd like to do it.

**Edit 2**: If you downvote a question, please leave a comment explaining why so the author can improve the question.  Even though something is obvious to you, it may not be to the author (in this case... me :P).

Comment: `typeof null !== Boolean` and....

Comment: In the example each value looks like string (in double quotes) except `null`.

Comment: @rayon - It's not that simple, they all come in as strings (see the example) except for the nulls.  Also we can only use JS types for integer, boolean, float, and string. For dates we would need to try to do Date parse on each one to a datetime and see if it works.

Comment: @AKS yes - that's why this isn't as easy as it appears at first glance.  I'm going to need to write something for this, and checking if anything exists already.

Comment: you can `typeof JSON.parse(val)`; after that, the exceptions will be strings, and you need to check the objects for Array and the Strings for Dates.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis - that's a good idea I'll give it a try

Comment: What are you using to serve that data to your client, any frameworks? Ideally that parsing would be done before it event leaves the server so the JSON is in the correct format when the client receives it.

Comment: Another good point thanks - right now it's using the PG gem for Rails to query from a postgres database.  Let me see why my integers and floats are coming back as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quick example of using `JSON.parse` and `typeof` to identify types:

```
var o={
  id: "1",
  email: "donnyp@gmail.com",
  is_subscribed: null,
  name: "Don P",
  created_at: "2015-01-18 18:16:32"
};
for(var it in o){ var v=o[it];
  try{v=JSON.parse(v);}catch(y){} //try to turn strings into literals
  if(!+v && Date.parse(v)){ v="date"; }else{ v=typeof v;} // find date strings (json encoded), not numbers
  if(v=="object" && Array.isArray(o[it])) v="array"; // [] vs {}
  if(v=="object" && !o[it]) v="null"; // null is and Object (doh!)
  o[it]=v;
}

o;/*  ~== {
  "id": "number",
  "email": "string",
  "is_subscribed": "null",
  "name": "string",
  "created_at": "date"
};*/
```

it's pretty close to your example output, but using JS types instead of SQL types, which JS cannot actually determine from JSON, since JSON makes specific number types like `int` ambiguous.